# calling a spring controller from xhrPost doesnot redirect

Tags: spring, dojo

I am calling a spring controller method from dojo xhrPost and I need to redirect to a new html from the controller method. But controller returns back to the dojo in javascript instead of moving to a new page.

my javascript:

```
var xhrArgs={
                        url:"/tradeIn/submitTradeIn",
                        postData:dojo.toJson(tradeInDetails),
                        handleAs:"text",
                        headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"}
                        /*load:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            label=data;
                            if(data =="fail"){
                                location.reload(true);
                                window.location="/Fail";
                            }
                            else{
                                window.location="/success";



                            }
                        }*/
                }

                var deferred=dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

my spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/tradeIn/submitTradeIn", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public    String submitTradeIn(@RequestBody TradeInDetails tradeDetails) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    List<byte[]> labelList=new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    ShippingInfo shippingInfo=new ShippingInfo();
    shippingInfo.setAddress1(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getAddress1());
    shippingInfo.setAddress2(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getAddress1());
    shippingInfo.setCity(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getCity());
    shippingInfo.setCompany(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getCompany());
    shippingInfo.setDayPhone(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getDayPhone());
    shippingInfo.setEmail(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getEmail());
    shippingInfo.setEvePhone(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getEvePhone());
    shippingInfo.setFirstName(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getFirstName());
    shippingInfo.setLastName(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getLastName());
    shippingInfo.setState(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getState());
    shippingInfo.setZip(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getZip());
    shippingInfo.setCountry(tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getCountry());
    List<ReturnRequestLabel> label; 
    List<TradeInClubs> tradeInList1= new ArrayList<TradeInClubs>();
    for(ClubDetails cl: tradeDetails.getClubDetails()){
        TradeInClubs tradeInclubs1=new TradeInClubs();
        tradeInclubs1.setClubMaterial(cl.getShaftType());
        tradeInclubs1.setClubType(cl.getClubType());
        tradeInclubs1.setManufacturer(cl.getClubManufacturer());
        tradeInclubs1.setModel(cl.getClubModel());
        tradeInclubs1.setTradeInValue(cl.getTradeInPrice());
        tradeInList1.add(tradeInclubs1);
    }
    try{

        ReturnFedexLabel returnFedexLabel = new ReturnFedexLabel();
        label=returnFedexLabel.fetchFedexLabel(tradeInList1, shippingInfo);
        byte[] labelImageData;

        String fedexLabelNumber=null;
        for(ReturnRequestLabel rl: label){
            labelImageData=rl.fedexReturnLabel.imageData;
            labelList.add(labelImageData);
            fedexLabelNumber=rl.trackingNumber;

        }
        File f=new File("label.jpg");
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(labelList.get(0)));

        ImageIO.write(img,"JPEG",f);
        int id=tradeInDao.insertQuery(shippingInfo,tradeInList1,fedexLabelNumber);
        byte[] pdfData=fedexLabelToPdf.printFedexLabel(labelList);
        emailTradeIn.emailTradeInDetails(pdfData,tradeDetails.getCustomerDetails().get(0).getEmail(),tradeInList1,id);
        System.out.println("here");


    } catch (Exception e){
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
        return "fail";

    }



    return "success";//Base64.encodeBase64String(labelList.get(0));
}
```

it is not moving to success page. it just stays in the current page

Comment: And why should it? You are using Ajax so the page is returned to your javascript result and you should handle it on the client. Also a redirect won't work (you aren't doing a redirect in your code but still) as that would be transparently handled by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and see what deferred is, it is probably "success".

From http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/quickstart/ajax.html:

> dojo.xhrPost xhrPost will create an Ajax request using the HTTP POST
>   method and is usually used to submit data to a service. It returns
>   data to a callback. The callback is defined as a member of the object
>   used to create the request (the property-bag), or by using the
>   dojo.Deferred.then() method.
>
> For complete details and examples, see the dojo.xhrPost documentation.

if you need to change the page from the controller it shouldn't be an ajax request.  If you can change it from the client side then you can continue with the ajax request and respond accordingly.